# Setting an attribute in jQuery and then retrieving it

Tags: jquery

I have

`var results="<div title='"+id+"'><img src='"+thumb+"'></div>";`

I'm rendering this out to the page, and then later trying to retrieve the id variable. To do this, I have:

`$("#results").click(function() { 
var id=$(this).attr("title"); });`

Right now, id is returning as undefined. I think I'm not setting the attribute right in the first place. How do I do this correctly? Let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Comment: I think there are a few ways to look at what's going on here. I think you'll probably need to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click handler `this` is pointing to `#results` and the `title` is being set to some other div. You need to find that `div` and get the `title` attribute from it. If `#results` is the same `div` to which you are setting the `title` then there should be `id="results"` in that div since you are selecting it by id.

`results` is a JavaScript varaible, are you looking for something like this

```
$(results).click(function() { var id=$(this).attr("title"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the ID, you need to retrieve `"id"` instead of `"title"`:

```
var id=$(this).attr("id");
```

...though you really don't need a jQuery method for this:

```
var id = this.id;
```

---

Or if you're trying to select the element by its *variable* name "results", you just can't do that. It needs to be an attribute of the element itself, not the name of some variable reference to it.

Comment: The dom element ID is obviously "results" from the code he posted. By ID he means the title.

Comment: @Greg: Thank you for that comment and the accompanying down-vote. Yes, you're right that OP probably want's the title. It is not obvious that the ID is actually *"results"*. It could be that he's trying to select by variable name, which of course wouldn't work. I addressed this possibility in my answer.

Comment: -1, It is obvious that #results selects the dom object with id=results....obviously

Comment: @Greg: Here you go again. Alright, how is it obvious? Where is the ID in the HTML string? It isn't there. But what's the name of the variable? *"results"* Just because OP is doing `$("#results")` *does not mean* that there's an element in the DOM with that ID. In fact, since `.attr("title")` is returning `undefined`, that would seem to indicate that there is no such element with that ID.

Comment: Or a more plausible guess would be that he forgot to add it to the DOM. I highly doubt someone would try and retreive the ID of something he already knows and is static. And I'm sorry but trying to use a selector on a JavaScript variable name makes no sense at all. Its very unlikely that is the mistake.

Comment: @Greg: I agree that it would be a very unusual mistake, but I don't know anything about the asker, and don't want to make any assumptions. If he simply forgot to add the ID, then it's ultimately the same issue of attempting to make an impossible DOM selection. Anyway, a little more info and feedback from the asker would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From your example there, what has the id="results" on it?  I'm assuming it's not your div with the title attribute.

try this:

```
$("#results div[title]").click(function() { var id=$(this).attr("title"); });
```

or better yet just add a class to that div

```
var results="<div class='result' title='"+id+"'><img src='"+thumb+"'></div>";

$("#results .result").click(function() { var id=$(this).attr("title"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make a lot of sense unless you left something out. I'm assuming you're adding results to the DOM somehow? If that's the case, you haven't assigned it an ID unless there is more javascript code missing. So when you retreive the identifier with ID of "results" are you getting anything?

Try printing out the length of `$("#results")` ...are you getting anything?

`attr("title")` is the correct way to read an attribute, but this is not synonymous with ID, so I'm a bit confused. Your ID is of course results, as indicated by your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code so you can reference the div - I'm using the id "theDiv", but you can use anything:

```
var results="<div id='theDiv' title='"+id+"'><img src='"+thumb+"'></div>";
```

I'm rendering this out to the page, and then later trying to retrieve the id variable. To do this, I have:

```
$("#results").click(function() { var id=$('#theDiv').attr("title"); });
```